# passing properties of image tag of html control from code behind in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

My HTML code is below

```
img id="img1" src="" alt="" runat="server" 
    data-zoom-image="**images/large/Best select basmati rice.png**"
```

Code behind code in below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        img1.Attributes["src"] = "~/images/small/Best select basmati rice.png";
       //img1.Attributes.Add("data-zoom-image", "~/images/large/best-select-basmati-rice.png");
       //img1.Attributes["data-zoom-image"] = "~/images/large/best-select-basmati-rice.png";
    }
```

My intention is to pass image into "data-zoom-image" property from code behind,

I have tried in the above but , i can pass src value, but not data-zoom-image.

Please suggest me to come from this issue.